# Trying to automatically open a image after startup/login via a bash script (Raspberry OS / Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, image, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-os

**Hello,**

I created a script(Bash) that opens an image in fullscreen.
The script works fine when I execute it.
I use crontab to start it after reboot and that also works fine (I'm printing if it ran and it did), the only issue is that the image is not opening at all.

Also I wrote another script that gets executed in this script(not in the code snippet) and that prints who the USER is. So if I execute it so it's soeren(me), if I am on root its 'root' and if the autostart thing executes it it's just empty.

So my assumption is that it's because the script gets not executed for me/my Desktop?
If that makes sense, I have no idea and need it for a work related project.
I use pqiv or open or xdg-open, they all work normally, but not when the script gets executed.

This is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Opens picture in fullscreen
#pqiv --fullscreen /home/soeren/Desktop/image.png

# TEST COMMAND
su -c 'open /home/soeren/Desktop/image.png' soeren

open /home/soeren/Desktop/image.png
#xdg-open /home/soeren/Desktop/image.png

# Prints that the script ran
echo "The script ran at: " `date` > /home/soeren/Desktop/script.txt
```

If you need more information feel free to ask for it.

Greetings,
Sören aka. Arktikus

Comment: Maybe a timing problem? The script runs before the ui is initialized?

Comment: @HelgeDerenthal also thought about that but a sleep didn't worked.

Comment: Since you are using Linux, I guess that you are using a Window manager based on the X Window System. X conceptionally manages several physical terminals (this dates back to the time where it was common to have hooked several screens on on computer). Nowadays it is more likely to have several monitors on your PC. To show a new window, X needs to know on which screen it should be displayed. This can be done, for instance, by setting the environment variable `DISPLAY`. Are you sure that your `open` does not write something to stderr?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the GUI process is `gnome-shell`

can try:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT_COUNT=60

until pgrep gnome-shell ; do
  (( TIMEOUT_COUNT -- ))
  [[ $TIMEOUT_COUNT -eq 0 ]] && echo "TIMEOUT" > /home/soeren/Desktop/script.txt && exit 1
  sleep 1
done

open /home/soeren/Desktop/image.png && echo "The script ran at:  $(date)" > /home/soeren/Desktop/script.txt
```